# Ensuring a parameter must be pointer (or interface, which internally a pointer)

Tags: go

Sometimes we make a function that like C#'s `out` in the parameter, just like `json.Unmarshal` or any kind of unmarshal function.

How in Go compile time (instead of runtime) we can make sure that the variable that being passed is a pointer or an interface?

In runtime I can do something like this:

```golang
func mustStructPtr(f interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(f)
    if v.Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("not a pointer: %T", f))
    }
    v = v.Elem() // dereference the pointer
    if v.Kind() != reflect.Struct { // TODO: non null map or slice also ok
        panic(fmt.Errorf("not struct; is %T", f))
    }
}
```

How to enfoce this on compile time in Golang? so something like this are allowed

```golang
var myStruct MyStruct
myFunc(&myStruct) // ok, because pointer
myFunc(myStruct) // <-- not ok, because this cannot receive
var x interface{} = &mystruct
myFunc(x) // ok, because interface to pointer 
x = myStruct
myFunc(x) // <-- not ok, because interface to non pointer

var y map[string]interface{}
myFunc(y) // ok, because map internally a pointer

var z = []myStruct{}
myFunc(&z) // ok, because a pointer
```

Comment: Since Go1.18 you can use [type constraints](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_constraints). However the *dynamic* type of an interface is called *dynamic* for a reason, so there is no way to constrain that at the compile time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really ensure that. If you really want a pointer I guess you could make your function generic and have it accept `*T`, but then you still don't know that T is a struct and it won't work with an interface.

You can catch this with linters (at least for json.Unmarshal) and otherwise, unit testing.

Comment: yup currently using unit test to catch this bug, since we're still using 1.17

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches to increase type safety in your case would be to declare a new type and enforce the check on creation.

```
type PointerOrInterface struct {
    val interface{}
}

func NewPointerOrInterface(val interface{}) PointerOrInterface {
    // check
    return PointerOrInterface{
        val: val,
    }
}
```